# Is there a way to group dataframe by its values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a the following dataframe:

```
Out[56]: 
   input  on_time
0      2      1.1
1      4      2.2
2      8      3.4
3      5      3.5
4      6      6.2
5     11      8.4
6     13      8.4
```

With on_time being a timestamp in my actual code. I want to group the inputs which have an on_time value close to each other (within a configurable range of each other) and add them to the dataframe (with on_time value being the highest off the two). Which would result in the following dataframe:

```
Out[60]: 
   input  on_time
0      2      1.1
1      4      2.2
2      8      3.4
3      5      3.5
4      6      6.2
5     11      8.4
6     13      8.4
7    8/5      3.5
8  11/13      8.4
```

I think I am able to do this with some iterations and loops, but is there a way of doing this in just a few lines?

Comment: How do you define `close to each other`? There has to be some limit.

Comment: Imagine that your fourth observation for input=5 has on_time=2.8 instead of 3.5 and the "neighbour catch radius" is 0.6. What do you want then in the additional outputs: the three observations for inputs 4, 8, 5 or for each of the three observations list it with the closest neighbour(s), then there would be one for each that has a close neighbour (or two max,  if the higher and lower are equidistant)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sort` the values, then define some threshold for differences below which you group values. Aggregate the columns, so that we join the 'input', pick the max of the on_time column and also calculate the `size` so we can subset to only the groups that had more than one value. `concat` the result in the end.

```
thresh = 0.2

df = df.sort_values('on_time')
grps = df['on_time'].diff().gt(0.2).cumsum()

res = (df.groupby(grps).agg(input=('input', lambda x: '/'.join(x.dropna().astype(str)), ),
                            on_time=('on_time', 'max'), 
                            size=('on_time', 'size')) 
         .query('size >= 2')
         .drop(columns='size'))

pd.concat([df, res], ignore_index=True)
#   input  on_time
#0      2      1.1
#1      4      2.2
#2      8      3.4
#3      5      3.5
#4      6      6.2
#5     11      8.4
#6     13      8.4
#7    8/5      3.5
#8  11/13      8.4
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked. I had to use it like this though: 
`agg(inputs=pd.NamedAgg(column = 'inputs', aggfunc = lambda x: '/'.join(x.dropna().astype(str))), 
                     on_time=pd.NamedAgg(column = 'on_time', aggfunc = 'max')`